# How do I create block diagrams in Microsoft Office without using Visio?

Tags: microsoft-office, diagrams

I need to create block diagrams (which will simply consist of rectangulars connected to each other with arrows, summing and multiplication circles). Microsoft Office 2013 is installed in my school lab, but Microsoft Visio is not included in it (the lab manager said that they had to pay more for Visio and it is not used much in our department).

Installed Office tools are:

- Access
- Excel
- InfoPath Designer & Filler
- Lync
- OneNote
- Outlook
- PowerPoint
- Publisher
- SkyDrive
- Word

I haven't ever used any MS Office tool other than Word and Excel. So, I don't know much about most of the ones listed above. Which of these tools can I use to create block diagrams?

A block diagram which is very similar to what I want to design:
[image: block diagram example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SmartArt or Shapes in Excel. Just go to the Insert tab and click on SmartArt or Shapes. It's not as easy as Visio makes it, but you can still do it.

BTW, SmartArt is annoying to use for the kind of flow chart you want to create. I would recommend the regular Shapes.

Example:

[image]

EDIT: Forgot to mention that you can pretty much do this in Word and PowerPoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can do flowcharts [like these](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/flowchart-diagram-examples-TC101875490.aspx) in PowerPoint.

[image]